# Where can I find Civ VI's logfiles on Mac?

Tags: technical-issues, mods, macos, civilization-6

I'm trying to play Civilization VI, but I can't load a game due to unsupported mods. I'm trying to find the logfiles, but there is no documentation as far as I can see as to where they are on Mac. Can anyone give me a pointer?

Comment: Is there a similar location on Macs to that of the AppData folder on Windows? Perhaps try that location if so

Comment: @TimmyJim That would be `~/Library/Application Support` for user-local data, and `/Library/Application Support` for global data

Comment: Neither of them have anything with Civ or Sid Meier's or anything

Comment: @TimmyJim Turns out there is one. No Logs folder or anything though

Comment: Hello @CATboardBETA. I think the question is fine with both the civ-6 and mods tag. No need for a civilization-6-mods tag.

Comment: @Fredy31 Ah. Since there were many other games [minecraft-mods] and the like, I thought it might make sense

Comment: Bounty expires in one day. Please answer!